# Git: How to auto update my local branch when a change happens in remote tracking branch?

Tags: git, shell

I want to run something in the background which basically does a `git pull --rebase` whenever some changes happen in my remote branch. Most of the time it work silently in the background if there are no conflicts. In there is a conflict it just leaves me in the rebase-resolve-conflict stage and until I resolve everything it waits. How do I do this? Is there an existing software that already does this?

Comment: You would need to add a hook to a remote repository or run a job every x minutes locally.

Comment: On which git server is your repository hosted? Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, ..?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni: Why does that matter? I am asking the question generically for any remote Git server...

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: This is something where I don't have control over what runs in remote repo but I can only control or install things in my local dev machine

Comment: @pathikrit It matters because some solutions have features like web hooks, but as you said, you want something that runs locally on your own machine.

Comment: @pathikrit One more way is to add a post-receive hook (assuming you have access on the server side). In this post receive you can run any script you would want, in your case it would be to update your local branch. More details on post-receive hook can be found here https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks. You may want to refer to some sample examples on post receive hooks as well.

Comment: Note that there are two types of conflicts: conflicts when merge/rebasing local unpushed commits and conflicts when re-applyling a local stash of local uncommitted changes. You may have either or both of these types of changes. Your script should handle both gracefully.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have control on the remote repository, one solution is to use [crontab](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) to run periodically `git fetch` or maybe even a `git pull --rebase` as you propose. The exact command to choose depends on your workflow, personally I prefer to use a `git fetch` because I can decide when and how to merge or rebase.

To run the command periodically run:

```
crontab -e
```

And add a line such as:

```
* * * * * git -C PATH_TO_LOCAL_REPO fetch
```

or

```
* * * * * git -C PATH_TO_LOCAL_REPO pull --rebase
```

This will run the git command every minutes with your user permissions.

If you want to apply the git command on a list of repository, you can can add the line:

```
* * * * * /home/myself/scripts/git-refresh.sh
```

where git-refresh is a script that apply on all your repositories.

The `-C` option allows you to run a git command without changing directory. From the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git--Cltpathgt):

> `-C <path>`
>
> Run as if git was started in "path" instead of the current working directory.

Comment: But I have to add this manually for every repo I have on my desktop! I have possibly hundreds of repos on my machine. How can I do it in a less manual way e.g. I run a script like `git-keep-fresh.sh &` in a terminal in the root of git project I am in. Secondly, how does this handle the 2nd part of my question regarding conflicts etc

Comment: I've updated my answer to take the multi-repository aspect into account. For the conflict resolution, it sometimes need to be manual you cannot automatize it, in every cases.

Comment: @pathikrit : note that your initial question implied finding a solution for one single repo. A cronjob will allow you to run any script you want. You can have a script which scans your directories for possible git repositories (a starting point can be : `find $HOME -name .git`), or you can pass an explicit list of repositories (`cat $HOME/.repositories`).

Comment: @pathikrit : if you really have hundreds of repos lying around, and potential merge conflicts on each single one of them, it will probably not be convenient to have unresolved conflicts automatically appearing on your disk without you being notified.

Comment: @LeGEC: My original question implied I have a script that I can run in the working directory of a git repo. And, yes, I want it to stop updating if it detects a potential merge conflict (it can simply print a message to cmd line saying this).

Answer (score 0):

This process called as Syncing a fork

Sync a fork of a repository to keep it up-to-date with the upstream repository. Unfortunately GitHub doesn't have any automatic sync feature. But, it is trivial to add as a cron job on a server so that you don't have to do it manually. For instance:

cd /srv/mirrorrepo ; git fetch upstream master ; git push origin master

Following plugin might help

https://github.com/trilbymedia/grav-plugin-git-sync